# Zoho lead api not saving data for a field

Tags: zoho

Hi i am using zoho v2 apis to create lead on zoho. All the values are save but one value is not saving. Check the attached file.

[image]

i have tried "Last_Page_Url" and "last_page_url" nothing works.

Comment: You should be able verify the name by calling `/settings/fields?module=Leads` through the API

Comment: i used this api and able to find the correct name. curl "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/settings/fields?module=Leads"
-X GET
-H  "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.8cb99dxxxxxxxxxxxxx9be93.9b8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this api to get the api_name for the key.
curl "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/settings/fields?module=Leads"
-X GET
-H  "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.8cb99dxxxxxxxxxxxxx9be93.9b8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf"